# Runnig selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, grid, selenium-server

I am trying to run a test using the selenium server which will enable cross browser testing, but I'm getting this error

I have downloaded the standalone server and ran it through comand prompt and got a grid console such as the image file attached and my guess is only webdriver part is enabled and remote control part is not if so PLease guid me on how to solve this [Grid console][1]

this is the error
FAILED: test
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
Command duration or timeout: 256 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'AKHIL-PC', ip: '192.158.0.29', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you attach the error you are talking about to your question, this wil help to debug you problem.

Comment: Can you add the error message in plain text to the question? then you wont have to add a link

Comment: i went through the link you suggested and followed every step the only difference is in my grid console i am not getting "Remote Control (legacy)" option along with "WebDriver"

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you are missing chrome driver. did you download the chrome driver form [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)?

Did you add the chrome driver to your path variable

In Windows, goto System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced (Tab) -> Environment Variables

[image: System properties]

Under System variables, scroll to the Variable named Path -> Edit… (button) -> Variable value ->
Scroll to the end of the field, add a semicolon and append the local path of chromedriver.exe to the
end of the value field. Click OK:

[image: Path variable]

To verify, open the Command Line (Run cmd.exe) -> Type chromedriver ->Hit Enter -> ChromeDriver

Also, restart the selenium standalone hubs and nodes

Let me know if it works

EDIT:
And if you configure your node via a xml file like:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe",
      "binary":"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
    }
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "<address to hub>",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Change the webdriver.chrome.driver and binary to your own path.
and the  to your hub url
And start your node via:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version>.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
```

Comment: in comand prompt im getting     (Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.)

Comment: do your test run when you execute them now?

Comment: When i run my test on my local machine by using "System.setProperty" specifying driver path the test run perfectly but now i wanted to switch to grid testing because i wanted try testing on multiple machines with different configuration and I am not succeeding at this

Comment: Can you try the example about xml configuration? it is more specific then command line config